# Video Hosting for Customer Uploads

Tags: video, youtube

I am building a page for a client of mine for a video contest. He wants the users to upload the video directly to the site then the videos be viewable.

While I can code this by hand for compatibility and other reasons I believe this would be best handled by a video site such as YouTube or Vimeo. I have considered creating a channel on YouTube (or Vimeo) but from what I can tell I cannot allow 3rd parties to upload to that channel.

Are there any recommendations on a good (preferably free) video hosting service that will allow 3rd party videos to be uploaded to a channel that I control? (Control meaning I can remove videos that contain copyrighted or offending material.)

Comment: I believe YouTube has an API that will allow you to upload videos. Couldn't your page/app take the User Generated Content, and simply turn around and use the YouTube API to upload it to your channel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the videos are for a contest then I'd imagine they are subject to review and moderation? Then uploading to YouTube should be a secondary action.

Personally I would upload to website then review and manually add. YouTube offers massive exposure for you client. It would a terrible trade off for the sake of automation.

Comment: This is what I was considering. Though automation would be nice.

Answer (score 2):

This automation could be achieved via the Vimeo Advanced API. Upload access requires approval, so make sure to [create an app](https://developer.vimeo.com/apps) and request access before you go too far down this path.

Currently the API requires the user to upload to you, and then you upload to Vimeo, but this can be a fully automated process. [Upload Documentation](https://developer.vimeo.com/apis/advanced#upload-api)

By uploading via the api, this allows you to consolidate all videos into a single account. These videos could then be set as private until your client has approved or denied the video.